# 301 htaccess redirects with numbers in URLs

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect the following link:

```
http://domain.com/forum1/threads/1023/
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/forum2/showthread.php?t=1023
```

Please help me with the appropriate `.htaccess` rules.

I tried the following with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^forum1/thread/(\d+)/$ /forum2/showthread.php?t=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forum1/threads/([0-9]+)/?$ /forum2/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: That didn't work. I want anyone who clicks on the first link to be automatically redirected to the second one.

Comment: Oh got it, that wasn't clear from your question, let me edit.

Comment: So if user enters: `http://domain.com/forum2/showthread.php?t=1023` in the browser you want browser to display `http://domain.com/forum1/threads/1023/` ?

Comment: I want the URL http://domain.com/forum1/threads/1023/ to be automatically redirected to http://domain.com/forum2/showthread.php?t=1023.

Comment: Ok that was already there in my previous rule. Make sure this rule is first rule before any other rule and it also make sure there is no .htaccess in `forum1/` or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do your job with this

```
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum1/threads/(\d+)/$ /forum2/showthread.php?t=$1
```